# Define the order of several ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery collection with some div's. For each div I have to do two ajax calls, whereas the first call returns an id that gets used by the second call. All ajax calls take some time (lets say a second).

If I do something like this:

```
$divs.each(function(index, element) {
    $.get('/some/url').done(function (id) {
        $.post('/some/other/url?id=' + id).done(function() {
            $(element).doSomething();
        });
    })
});
```

then all *get* calls will be done first, and then all *post* calls. This is not wrong, however, I would prefer to execute the *post* calls as early as possible, in order to sooner show the first results to the user.

So I don't want:

```
get, get, get, get, get, get, get, get, post, post, post, post, post, post, ...
```

rather this:

```
get, get, get, get, get, post, get, post, get, post, get, post, get, post, ...
```

In other words: As soon as the first call for a div is done, start immediately the second call. Don't wait until all first calls were done.

I think I have to queue the calls somehow. Do I have to? Or how could I achieve this?

**Note: the browser executes only a limited amount of ajax calls in parallel. AFAIK 6 in Firefox by default ([Connections per Hostname](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)).** `$.get()` calls may be fast, but the connection limitations causes that the fetching may take some time. Would 6 queues help? Or should I have a queue for each div?

An extra task would be to cancel the whole processing, if that would be possible too.

**Update/Solution:** People didn't understand what my problem was. As some have recommended now I have used the [priorityQueue in async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#priorityQueue) library. With this I can reduce the number of pending connections and control the order of requests.

Comment: It would actually be fastest if you do it the way you're currently doing it. (unless you were able to combine them all into one of course.) Otherwise, the user will overall have to wait longer for it all to finish if you delayed any of the get requests.

Comment: @KevinB Do you think so? I see that the whole processing time won't change. It is just an re-ordering so that some results can be shown earlier.

Comment: Gotcha. Re-ordering would make it take longer overall, but would be perceived as being faster due to presenting a little bit of the results earlier. I'd suggest fetching the first, say, 3, then fetching the rest.

Comment: @KevinB Right, it's all about improving the user experience (a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Hi see if this approach can help you:

```
var divs = $("div");

recursiveFunction(divs);

function recursiveFunction(divs){
  var element = divs.shift();
  $.get('/some/url').done(function (id) {
     $.post('/some/other/url?id=' + id).done(function() {
        $(element).doSomething();
        if(divs.length > 0){
           recursiveFunction(divs);
        }
     });
  })

}
```

This way you can have get , post , get , post.

Comment: This would create a straight sequence of calls, right? But I'd like use the parallel execution as far as it is possible (Firefox: 6 parallel calls are possible).

Comment: You can change this to do parallel executions, don't you see this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with your code. Its just that you can't notice the trigger events.

For more control over the async calls, you can use https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#controlflow

lets say your each ajax (get and post) call takes 1sec and processing of each item in loop takes few milliseconds, say 10ms. So for 5 divs:

```
10ms 1st div
-> get sent

  20ms 2nd div 
  -> get sent

    30ms 3rd div 
    -> get sent

      40ms 4th div 
      -> get sent

        50ms 5th div 
        -> get sent
```

(total 50ms) all ajax queued, but 1st div's get is still under processing and will respond on `1010ms` and after that post req will be sent

Now as time proceed, following will happen

```
(all get requests sent)

    1010ms 1st div
    -> post sent

      1020ms 2nd div 
      -> post sent

        1030ms 3rd div 
        -> post sent

          1040ms 4th div 
          -> post sent

            1050ms 5th div 
            -> post sent
```

So from above order is

```
get1, get2, get3, get4, get5, post1, post2, post3, post4, post5
```

There's nothing wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong, but not optimal. Look at comments of the question.

Comment: Now it depends on the network latency. This above loop will be faster when network responds faster. Consider your requests are responding in 20ms, then the order will be different like `get1, get2, post1, get3, post2, get4, post3, get5, post4, post5`

 
And if both get and post URLs are on same server and same app, they can be handled in single AJAX call.

And as we are talking about optimisation, it is not good to send so many AJAX requests for the sake of initial UI setup

Comment: To optimise, you can ask for 5 IDs at once and then handle the POST requests separately one by one or simultaneously at once.

Comment: All gets are started nearly the same, that's true. But if you look into the network section of developer tools of a browser you will see that the first calls are started immediately, but the others are pending! See [Connections per Hostname](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network).

Comment: There are certain ways, one of them is HTTP2. And you can not escape from request count throttle, so best idea is to combine the requests. All 5 divs are independent of each other, so you can request IDs for them at once. Or you can have ID generation at client side. My point is that why we are having so many requests when things can be done in very few. For now  we are discussing for 5 divs but what about more divs, hence this way is not scalable.

Comment: Another approach is to implement web-sockets which is lightweight and is persistent, so many calls get completed in one connection and hence throttle can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The reason you're seeing delays is because all of your gets are thrown into the Javascript queue. Effectively the first gets are executed and then queuing up your posts requests, however, there are other gets in front of your posts already.

As pointed out by others, network latency and the server side time to process the get/post request will exacerbate this. The only real solution to improve the latency issue from a user's experience is to chunk the requests. Basically, queue up x get requests, say 4, then load x more get requests once those are done or use settimeout and guestimate a delay or trigger the subsequent requests via an event. In my opinion the latter two are hacks that won't scale well. I would suggest using the first option and download async js library and use the parallel() method to queue the first four and use the optional callback to kick off the next batch. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

The `$.get()` method returns asynchronously.

This means that you are correct, all `$.get()`s will be executed sequentially, synchronously, **however** the callback functions in each of them (the callbacks inside the `.done()`s) will be called asynchronously.

The time it takes till the callbacks are called can vary, while the time for the `$.get()`s to execute is practically 0, so the way you do it right now is fine.